# Can I create a Play! framework project and use existing Java code?

Tags: java, playframework

I'm currently in a project which already has some codebase in plain Java, we need to develop a new web application which will leverage on this plain Java code.

We already have code for database access, some business rules, etc. I really just want to use Play for the web development part and don't want to do a whole new implementation of models using a Play approach.

What I thought when looking for a Java web framework was to find something that I could embed in the project, start a server (like Jetty or something) in my application and it would take care of the web part. But reading Play's documentation I can only find examples on how to run Play, not how to embed it into some project.

What I want to know is: can I embed a Play application inside another application? If not, how can I use my already developed plain Java code inside a Play! project?

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Most probably you can, but I'm just only guessing. We don't know the structure your Java classes, number of them etc. etc. First just start by creating common Play actions (and routes etc), put your code in some packages and then try to call your existing methods from the actions. On the other hand if you're going to change it massively in the future and use a lot of Play's features, maybe it's better to rewrite it to the Play now, when it's relatively small yet. I don't know, you have to judge yourself.

Comment: Currently there's not a lot of code for this project and we always tried to use as few as possible 3rd party libraries. I think that it would be quite easy to integrate them without hassle, my problem is: how do I do that inside Play's project structure?

Comment: I don't think there's some special requirement, just add custom packages under the app (but not app/controllers as they are imported ie. to views automatically) and that's all

Comment: And that was it, thank you! It would be nice if you made your comment as an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide your existing code as a Jar file and call it from your Play app.

If your application is too big/this can't be done for whatever reason, create some API in your app that Play can connect to (via webservices, etc) and use it.

I would not recommend embedding Play inside, not because it can't be done (I'm sure it can) but would be messy and it is probably a good idea to keep the different concerns (web/whatever your app does) separated for easier maintenance/upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

If your codebase is small, you can try this solution:
put your code into app/ folder (should be generated by play).
3rd party jars addition explained here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/SBTDependencies